# Using numpy.max(B) funtion get different result in python 2.7, when B is a complex matrix. Why?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, matrix

I have a complex matrix B which shape is (81,64,11). Now I want to get the max in this matrix under python 2.7 and the numpy 1.11.1. I found a funny question:
if I use numpy.max(B), the function get the position of the max is B[34,25,9]. Whereas I use numpy.max(abs(B)), the function get the position of the max is B[33,27,9]. All detail are shown as the Figure. My question is how to compute the numpy.max(B) when B is complex matrix.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeOBB.png)

Comment: What results were you expecting?  There is no inherent ordering of complex numbers, as there is for reals.  Apparently, the ordering Numpy uses is lexicographic (compare the real parts, only if those are equal is the imaginary part compared) - which is utterly unrelated to comparing absolute values.

Comment: @ jasonharper. Thank you very much for your answer.